# Gerar uma combinação aleatória em cada linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Eu fiz um gerador de números que ficou assim:

```
import random
import math

for i in range(10):

    c1 = (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
    c2 = (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
    c3 = (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
for i in range(90):
 print  ('{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, ))
```

funciona quase tudo, quando eu executo o código no pycharm ele gera 90 combinações porem todas elas são iguais mas eu quero que sejam aleatória como se eu tivesse executando o código varias vezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando você definiu os valores randômicos para c1, c2 e c3 eles realmente foram randomicos e diferentes entre si, portando a função random cumpriu seu papel. Se você quiser que eles sejam randômicos dentro do for você precisa, para cada iteração, chamar o método random novamente.

```
import random

def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

for i in range(3): 
    print ('{}{}{}'.format(gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))
```

Comment: Um pequeno detalhe seria colocar `range(1, 10)` em vez do erray explícito, neste caso. Boa resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho, me passa seu contato que esse código vai me dar uma grana e eu te pago.

Comment: Não precisa @felipe, fique tranquilo. Nosso objetivo aqui é auxiliar a comunidade. Aliás, que bom que minha resposta resolveu seu problema. Grande abraço.